# Unable to launch terminal after downloading Python 3.7.7 and Pycharm on 20.04

Tags: python, gnome-terminal, 20.04

After downloading Python 3.7.7 and Pycharm, I can't start terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or any other way. When I tried to start terminal nothing happens. I'm unable to login  in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> screen also. How can I fix this?

Output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`:

```
rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 May 23 16:44 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5496816 Nis 18 05:59 /usr/bin/python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5496816 Nis 18 05:59 /usr/bin/python3.7m
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5457536 Nis 27 18:53 /usr/bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Nis 27 18:53 /usr/bin/python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Mar 13 15:20 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.8-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 384 Mar 28 05:39 /usr/bin/python3-futurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 388 Mar 28 05:39 /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108387/discussion-on-question-by-onurbasak-unable-to-launch-terminal-after-downloading).

Comment: yes , i done it with uppercase now and waiting didnt know case sensitive issue

Answer (score 1):

The default Python 3 version on Ubuntu 20.04 is 3.8. The apps/packages are compatible only with the default Python version and may fail if used the other versions. Since you have updated alternatives for `python3` and configured it to use Python 3.7, you need to revert the changes.

Since you aren't able to use TTY mode for some reasons, and have Pycharm, you can use the in-built terminal of Pycharm too. To use that, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `bash /path/to/the/pycharm/script`. Once launched, create a  new project and click on **Terminal** at the bottom of screen. To make Python 3.8 as the default Python 3 again, update the symbolic link using

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
```